# Get the offset of a span's startpoint using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to find the exact start point of a span.  However, when I use jQuery offset or jQuery position, all I get is the starting point of the span's bounding box, which is not very helpful.  Illustration of the problem available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/V6Gx6/13/

```
$('div').append('</br>'+$('span').outerHeight(true));
$('div').append('</br>'+$('span').offset().top);
$('div').append('</br>'+$('span').offset().left);
```

The "left" portion of the span's starting point should not be zero, since the span does not start at the beginning of the line.  Does anyone have a clever way of circumventing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$("span")[0].offsetLeft
```

or if you want in straight javascript:

```
document.getElementById("theSpanIWant").offsetLeft;
```

To get offsetRight of the last character in span something like this should work:

```
function getOffsetRight(el) {
    $(el).append("<span id='findme'></span>");
    return $(el).parent().width() - $("#findme")[0].offsetLeft;
};

$(window).on("resize",function(){
    $('div').append("</br>"+$('span')[0].offsetLeft);
    $('div').append("</br>"+getOffsetRight($('span')[0]));

});
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V6Gx6/17/

Comment: Wow, I knew there had to be an easy way!  Alright, one more thing: how would I get the bottom right corner (which could potentially come after a line break?  Sadly, there is no offsetRight property.

Comment: edited answer to get offsetRight. You will probably want to clean it up and definitely destroy the created span after calculating offset

Comment: Dude thank you!  I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Much appreciated :)